# centering navigation bar, to far over

Tags: html, css

```
.topnav {
background-color: #333;
overflow: hidden;
float: right;
width: 80%;
```

}

```
.topnav a {
float: left; width: 18%;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
```

}

```
.topnav a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
```

}

```
.topnav a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
```

}

NAV BAR if off a bit i want it centered with my page.
my site and go to menu page thats what im working with right now and u can see.
http://ist2w.kaplan.edu/1702A/IT117-02/PatrickMapes

Comment: Welcome to SO!

Have a good read here and come back and edit the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, also please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge).

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
nav { 
   text-align: center
} 
nav ul { 
  display: inline-block 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use it

```
    nav {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
     }
```

**have fun**